# When I try to print(query) , I get the result as <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x00000273CCF21D90>

Tags: regex, pymongo

When I try to `print(query)`, I get the result as    `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x00000273CCF21D90>`  whereas I want the entire document that contains primaryTitle that has `"Friday Night"`. Please help.

```
rgx = re.compile('.*Friday Night.*', re.IGNORECASE)  # compile the regex

query= db.IllegalCollect.find({"$primaryTitle": rgx})
```

Comment: You need to fetch the results of the query, not just print the query itself.

Comment: query should have additional functions for example if your familiar with the request library if you were to print(req) it would just give you the 200 response if successful but if you did print(req.json()) or print(req.text()) it would give you the actual data returned

Answer (score 0):

`find()` returns a cursor which you have to iterate to get the results; you can't just print the result as you have found. Your options are to use `find_one()` (will only return one record though); to use `list(query)` to convert to a list, or to iterate the cursor with a `for` loop.

The example below shows each method.

btw your `$primaryTitle` field in the find query won't work; you likely need `primaryTitle` without the `$`

```
import pymongo
import re
db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']

db.IllegalCollect.insert_one({'primaryTitle': 'Last Friday Night, Yeah we maxed our credit cards'})
db.IllegalCollect.insert_one({'primaryTitle': 'And got kicked out of the bar, So we hit the boulevard'})

rgx = re.compile('.*Friday Night.*', re.IGNORECASE)  # compile the regex

query = db.IllegalCollect.find_one({'primaryTitle': rgx})
print (query)

query = db.IllegalCollect.find({'primaryTitle': rgx})
print (list(query))

query = db.IllegalCollect.find({'primaryTitle': rgx})
for item in query:
    print (item)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :)